# Разница между cms и framework

Tags: php, cms, framework

Какая разница между cms и framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CMS или же Content Management System - это система, устанавливаемая на сервер и позволяющая управлять твоим сайтом и его содержимым. Подразумевается, что она изначально несет в себе все необходимые инструменты и интерфейс для редактирования сайта.

Фреймворк - это набор методов, способов и функций для ускоренного и более удобного создания каких либо приложений.

Answer (score 0):

cms - готовое решение + нужные плагины для сайта.

framework - набор компонентов для создания сайта

А вообще в google куча ответов на твой вопрос.